# CListBox SetScrollPos doesn't work

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog with a `CListBox` member with a vertical scroll bar which gets destroyed and recreated occasionally. On those occasions, I want the scroll bar to stay in the same position it was before destruction.

In the function that causes re-creation, I have this line:

```
int scrollPos = m_checkListCtrl.GetScrollPos(SB_VERT);
```

(`scrollPos` is then saved externally and passed again to the window on its creation.)

In the end of `OnInitDialog`, I call:

```
m_checkListCtrl.SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, scrollPos );
```

`scrollPos` is passed correctly, yet the scroll bar remains in its initial position. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: May be you need to do `UpdateData()` before and `UpdateData(FALSE)` after?

Comment: I call UpdateData() before GetScrollPos and UpdateData(FALSE) before SetScrollPos, still doesn't work.

Comment: You should call  `UpdateData(FALSE)` **after** `SetScrollPos`

Comment: And maybe `m_checkListCtrl.RedrawWindow()` between these two.

Comment: I tried:
  int res = m_checkListCtrl.SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, lastScroll);
  m_checkListCtrl.RedrawWindow();
  UpdateData(FALSE);
And also without m_checkListCtrl.RedrawWindow(); . Neither worked.

Comment: Are you also calling SetScrollRange() before calling SetScrollPos() ?

Comment: Use `CListBox::SetTopIndex` instead

Comment: I wasn't - I added it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should avoid destroying the listbox. Use `listbox.GetTopIndex` to save the index. `listbox.ResetContent()` to remove all items. Then `SetTopIndex`, it doesn't need anything else.

Comment: Likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Using `SetTopIndex` worked!

Yeah, I needed to get the listbox to its previous position after being destroyed (I can't keep from destroying it due to existing infrastructure issues).